# Working with d3 & nvd3 on an Angular2 final project w/angular-cli beta 15

Tags: angular, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-cli, ng2-nvd3

I am trying to get the combo `d3`, `nvd3` and `ng2-nvd3` to work on a Angular 2 project with `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.15`.

I have installed the packages with the corresponding `@types` via npm, `package.json` looks like this (irrelevant packages omitted):

```
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "3.5.16",
    "ng2-nvd3": "1.1.3",
    "nvd3": "1.8.4",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/d3": "0.0.33",
    "@types/nvd3": "1.8.32",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
  }
```

I included the `d3.js` and `nv.d3.js` as well as `nv.d3.css` in the `angular-cli.json` (packages are bundled correctly):

```
  "styles": [
    "../../../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../../../node_modules/d3/d3.js",
    "../../../node_modules/nvd3/build/nv.d3.js"
  ],
```

I created a `common` module for importing `ng2-nvd3` (I verified the code is bundled as well):

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { nvD3 } from "ng2-nvd3";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [nvD3],
    exports: [nvD3]
})
export class MyCommonModule {
}
```

Then, I imported the `common` module into the app module that expects to use it (in the `ActivityChartComponent`):

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [PaginationModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, routing, MyCommonModule],
    declarations: [ActivityChartComponent],
    exports: [PlatformComponent]
})
export class PlatformModule {
}
```

and here is the `ActivityChartComponent` template (the component code itself just calculates the data, it is irrelevant here):

```
<h5 class="card-title">{{title}}</h5>
<span *ngIf="description" class="chart-info">{{description}}</span>
<nvd3 [options]="chart" [data]="data"></nvd3>
```

I am getting an exception ( I masked the URLs in the stack trace with '...' to protect private data):

```
TypeError: groups.watchTransition is not a function
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/.../nv.d3.js:12243:20)
    at http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50272:16
    at d3_selection_each (http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50278:30)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.each (http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50271:12)
    at Array.chart (http://localhost:8000/.../nv.d3.js:11919:19)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.call (http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50285:14)
    at SVGGElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/.../nv.d3.js:6540:25)
    at http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50272:16
    at d3_selection_each (http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50278:30)
    at Array.d3_selectionPrototype.each (http://localhost:8000/.../main.bundle.js:50271:12)
```

To be able to debug this - I removed the `d3` and `nvd3` references from `angular-cli.json` and I imported them directly into the `index.html` instead.

Looking at the `d3` code, I couldn't find any reference to `watchTransition`, however `nvd3` adds the implementation on `d3.selection.prototype`.

snippet from `nv.d3.js`:

```
d3.selection.prototype.watchTransition = function(renderWatch){
    var args = [this].concat([].slice.call(arguments, 1));
    return renderWatch.transition.apply(renderWatch, args);
};
```

When debugging, I see the prototype does not have the `watchTransition` reference...

Any ideas, leads or information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

OK, managed to solve this.
The problem was, that when the `d3` and `nvd3` were bundled via `angular-cli.json` they were bundled into the `scripts.bundle` and the application code in `main.bundle` and that apparently caused them to have different scopes.

I imported them in the common module instead of in the angular-cli config and that made everything be bundled in `main.bundle`.

So, common module now looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import "d3";
import "nvd3";
import { nvD3 } from "ng2-nvd3";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [nvD3],
    exports: [nvD3]
})
export class MyCommonModule {
}
```